# Drop Down Menu Quirk ... when <div> controlled by CLASS vs ID

Tags: html, css

Have a fairly simple menu bar (with hover drop downs) that works fine.  See Code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.text-outline {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: larger;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #663333, 1px -1px 0 #663333, -1px 1px 0 #663333, 1px 1px 0 #663333;
}

#div_menu_main {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:135px;
  width:1200px;  
  overflow: visible;
  height:26px;
  background-color: #996633;
  z-index:-1;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:135px;
  width:1200px;  
  overflow: visible;
  height:26px;
  z-index:10;  
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #663333;
}
/*
#div_menu_main_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:135px;
  width:1200px;  
  overflow: visible;
  height:26px;
  z-index:10;  
}
#div_menu_main_overlay a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#div_menu_main_overlay a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #663333;
}
*/

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-left:5px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #996633;
  min-width: 130px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-left:5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #663333;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<title>Untitled</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="div_menu_main"></div>
  <div class="navbar text-outline"><!--textonly-->
  <!--<div id="div_menu_main_overlay" class="text-outline"><!--textonly-->  
  <a href="#home">HOME&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#createpost" style="margin-left:335px;">CREATE POST</a>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn text-outline">REVISE POST<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#lostpassword">LOST PASSWORD</a>
      <a href="#revisepost">REVISE POST</a>
      <a href="#revisepost2">REVISE POST2</a>
      <a href="#revisepost3">REVISE POST3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#search">SEARCH</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn text-outline">DONATIONS<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="donators">DONATORS</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn text-outline">HELP<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#faqs">FAQs</a>
      <a href="#guidelines">GUIDELINES</a>
      <a href="#lostpassword">LOST PASSWORD</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
<a href="#news">NEWS</a>  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn text-outline">ABOUT<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#friends">FRIENDS</a>
      <a href="#sitetraffic">SITE TRAFFIC</a>
      <a href="#advertising">ADVERTISING</a>
      <a href="#why">WHY?</a>
      <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#contactmia">CONTACT MIA</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Normally one div would be used for the background and the menu items, however, I have to weave around some graphics so the "menu bar" is in the < div id="div_menu_main" > and the menu items and dropdowns are in the < div class="navbar text-outline" >.  All works fine ... dropdowns behave as expected, ie stacked.

However, am integrating this into a larger project where there is already an extensively used "navbar" class, and given there is only one main menu, decided to use < div id=div_menu_main_overlay class="text-outline" > ...basically changing class=navbar for id=div_menu_main_overlay.  Converted the .navbar references over to #div_menu_main_overlay ... and then it happens.  NOTE: For ease I have both flavors of CSS code in the example, just commenting out the version not being tested.

The unexpected behavior is the dropdown content are now acting as if the anchor element is float: left; vs none;.  Played around with several possibilities and even though all I have to do is change the class name to something over than .navbar, this subtlety has piqued my interest on what is the problem.

Comment: Please Share as snippet.

Comment: SunilR.  Looks like @GucciBananaKing99 beat me to it.  Thank you GBK99!   What is running works but if you uncomment the #div_menu_main_overlay (3) statements and comment out the (3) navbar statements, you will see the dropdowns go sideways.  Just looking to understand what is causing the diff when declaring the div an ID vs applying a Class.